How to setup react testing library with next.js app router and joy ui (MUI)
I'm having difficulties setting up react testing library with next.js app router and Joy UI (MUI).
Joy UI instructions for working with next.js are here: https://mui.com/joy-ui/integrations/next-js-app-router/
There is issues with creating a RTL setup using ThemeRegistry.
I have minimal reproducible example using codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/weathered-shadow-yk8gls
I've tried mocking various values in ThemeRegistry with no success.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
